# How to split time left in days,hours,minutes,seconds in query

Tags: php, mysql

Below is my table structure

[image]

Now I am in need of a query in whicn I can display the days,hours,minutes,second left for that event.

I have use this query

```
select title,`date`,subject ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'),'2013-05-25 12:00:00')  as dayleft ,TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'),'2013-05-25 12:00:00')  as hourleft from jos_holidays where `date` > CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30')
```

and the above results me

[image]

But my need to get exact time left includes days,hours,minutes and seconds and display it in seperate columns. Can I achive this in query? Though this can be achievable in PHP.

Also the date `"2013-05-25 12:00:00"` value in query is hard coded . Can be make it dynamic too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query:

**[SQLFIDDLEExample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dc654/16)**

```
SELECT title,
       `date`,
       subject ,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'), `date`) AS dayleft,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'), `date`)
       - TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'), `date`)*24 AS hourleft,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'),  `date`) -
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'), `date`)* 60 AS minuteleft,
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'), `date`)- 
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30'),  `date`)*60 AS secondleft
FROM jos_holidays
WHERE `date` > CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, '+05:30')
```

Comment: getting error on  `AS dayleft
       MOD(HOUR` . what is this exactly

Comment: Modulo operation, returns the remainder... what error, i think with dates is something wrong, because mysql have such a function... insert int http://sqlfiddle.com/ your sample data by pushing DLL and I will check.

Comment: Ah you missed comma in the end of `dayleft`

Comment: yes , beautiful :) but it dosent shows the difference after some day
http://i.imgur.com/fCvM3sn.png
Is it limited for some days and month . Please check th pic

Comment: Ok, edited answer, but test before using, because I think there can be some bugs:) I try to upgrade this query to be better.

Comment: But why the time hours,minutes and seconds are different .Logically since the time is same, except days everyting should be same

Comment: Ok edited answer not very beautiful but now works i think. Didn't find any simplier solution...

Answer (score 0):

Try like

```
$diff = strtotime($date) - time();
echo "tile left is ".date('Y-m-d H-m-i',$diff);
```

Comment: I am looking solution in mysql. Your solution will definitely will work in php

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you can use

```
$now = new DateTime(); // or use any start date you want
$date = new DateTime($row['date']); // your sql query result
$diff = $now->diff($date);
```

This makes $diff a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object that contains all the information you are looking for. It does require PHP 5.3+.

I'm not sure if it would be possible to get the same information directly from MySQL. But I would assume that it's mainly for display purposes, so calculating this in PHP from available information is not too much overhead.

Answer (score 0):

its work i have used this query

```
 SELECT 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),'2013-06-23') AS dafLeft, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),'2013-06-23')-TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),'2013-06-23')*24 AS hourLeft,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),'2013-06-23')-TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),'2013-06-23')*60 AS minLeft,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),'2013-06-23')-TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),'2013-06-23')*60 AS secLeft;

For dynamic just '2013-06-23' to your field name (date field name) and fetch like you do in other table.
```

Happy coding!! :)

Comment: `'2013-06-23' to your field name (date field name)` . Can I pass my own colum name dynamically in the query . Can you show some example?

Comment: If you see my tables, I want to pass `date` column value in query dynamically

Comment: Ofcouse @Deonia this is example, if any confusion plz ask i will be happy to help you :)

------------------------------------------------
`**

SELECT 
    id, name, start_date,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),start_date) AS dafLeft, 
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),start_date)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY,NOW(),start_date)*24 AS hourLeft,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),start_date)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR,NOW(),start_date)*60 AS minLeft,
    TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),start_date)-TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,NOW(),start_date)*60 AS secLeft
FROM
   tbl_products
Where 
   id = 10;
**`